# Memory problems while copying data from one mysql table to another

Tags: php, mysql, memory

I need to fetch, convert and then insert 4 000 000 rows into another table. 
Needles to say, a memory exhausted error kicks in after 300 000~ entries. After every loop allocated memory increases by exactly 160 bytes.
I know that using mysql_unbuffered_query() would be possible, although it forces me to fetch all result rows before I can execute another query, which ends up in memory exhausted error again. So, what's the best way to do this in a single run?

```
mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
mysql_select_db($db);

$getOldData = mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM players_online 
ORDER by id ASC
");
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($getOldData);

for ($i=0; $i < $numRows; $i++) { 
$oldData = mysql_fetch_assoc($getOldData);
$hour = explode(':', $oldData['hour']);
$quarters = $hour[0] * 4 + $hour[1] / 15;

$update = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO players_online_2 (world_id, players_online, quarters_past_midnight, date)
    VALUES (
        '".$oldData['world_id']."', 
        '".$oldData['players_online']."', 
        '".$quarters."', 
        '".$oldData['date']."'
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        world_id='".$oldData['world_id']."', 
        players_online='".$oldData['players_online']."', 
        quarters_past_midnight='".$quarters."', 
        date='".$oldData['date']."'
");

if (mysql_error()) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die();
}

echo memory_get_usage().PHP_EOL;
```

}

Comment: any reason for not doing it directly in the database?

Comment: Some conversion needs to be done inbetween.

Comment: As the only conversion of data you seem to be doing is a minor date/time change, you could still do this as an INSERT INTO... SELECT FROM directly on the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/) will let you [export](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-manage-server-export-to-disk.html) the old database and [import](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-manage-server-import-from-disk.html) it into the new location.

With that said though, if you want to do this in PHP, you should probably not return the entire table in one shot. You could use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to split the query into pages, and then execute one page at a time. Something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $Limit; $i++)
{
  // SELECT * FROM players_online ORDER by id ASC LIMIT 1000 OFFSET ' . $i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single query, something like:

```
INSERT INTO players_online_2 (world_id, players_online, quarters_past_midnight, date)
    select world_id, players_online, quarters_past_midnight, date
    FROM players_online po
    ORDER by id ASC
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    world_id = po.world_id,
    players_online = po.players_online, 
    quarters_past_midnight = po.quarters_past_midnight, 
    date = po.date;
```